# php timezone "Etc/GMT+5" equivalent to UTC ("Etc/UTC+5" ?)

Tags: php, timezone

I wanted to convert a date in php from UTC format to UTC+5.
If it was from GMT to GMT+5 i would simply do:

```
$date_str = '2011-04-01 12:00:00'; //ex:from database

$date = new DateTime($date_str,new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Etc/GMT+5'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //testing
```

In the php timezone lists [here](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php), there isn't no 'Etc/UTC+5' equivalent.

**Is there a way to do convert from UTC to UTC+5 in php?**

or would it make the same result whit the GMT example?

would it be wrong to convert 'UTC' to 'Etc/GMT+5'?

Notes:

- the date I'm actually using (from my database) is in the UTC format.
- I still get a bit confused abut the difference between UTC and GMT time formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *civil timezones*, GMT and UTC are nowadays considered equivalent. Strictly speaking, they are not, but in this context you may more than likely safely pretend that they are.

Comment: It helps to know that it wont be any problems, but still i liket to make completely sure. would the conversion from 'UTC' -> 'GMT' -> 'Etc/GMT+5' be the exact way to do it?

Comment: @Seeker: Well that still gives you GMT+5. And it's the same as "UTC" -> "Etc/GMT+5" .. the middle step is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

GMT is old and busted, UTC is the new hotness. Other than that, they're equivalent enough to consider interchangeable.

Comment: Ty for your answer, but if I really wanted to make a perfect conversion do you know what would be the way to do it in php using the 'List of Supported Timezones - others' that i put a link to?